# Central Error Page "Web Service" (External Custom Error Pages)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-error-pages, custom-errors, custom-error-handling

**GOAL SUMMARY:**

I would like to create an application that will render custom error pages for other intranet applications. The goal is to centralize the content of these pages so that it may be managed in a single application.

**DEVELOPMENT CONTEXT:**

The language, framework, and IDE are C#, .NET Framework, and Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 respectively. I doubt that these make much difference but they do provide some context.

**UNDESIRABLE SOLUTIONS:**

My research has led me to several solutions that I would like to avoid discussing since many other answered questions exist already regarding them. These solution include but are not limited to the following:

- HTML: iframe, object, and embed
- AJAX: Javascript, jQuery
- C#: web client

My reasoning for wishing to avoid these solutions seems off-topic so I will only include it if necessary.

**HOPES AND DREAMS:**

Instead, I would love to set the the appropriate endpoints for custom error handling in a configuration file similar to how I might if those endpoints were on the same server as the application.

For example:

```
<error statusCode="404" path="/error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

However, setting path to a URL does not appear to "work."

For example:

```
<error statusCode="404" path="http://localhost:16715/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

This renders a completely blank page instead of the desired webpage.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I configure a web application in the described context to render custom error webpages that are hosted by this new, supposed application that I wish to develop?

**THOUGHTS FOR DISCUSSION:**

Considering that this information was not easily discovered and I do not know of others developing such applications, is this even a good idea? Should I totally abort this concept altogether? Am I blindly overlooking security risks?